# popping to root view in navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have one navigation controller with three views. I push the three view controllers onto the navigation controller's stack and want to pop all the pushed view controllers at once by the click on a button. I would like to be able to do that from any pushed view controller...

Please can you help me and give me pointers on how I could do that?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way for the rootviewcontroller to know that this action happened, so it can give a feed back like "Done bro!" ?

Comment: `navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)` for Swift